# Ansible: Upgrade all packages to the latest version EXCEPT foo, bar

Tags: ansible

How can one write an Ansible playbook to upgrade all Ubuntu packages except Java and PostgreSQL?

with the following task I can upgrade all packages to the latest version:

```
- name: Upgrade all packages to the latest version
  apt:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
```

Is there a way to add a list of packages to ignore for update/upgrade?

UPDATE:

Thanks to Vladimir's answer I updated the Ansible Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: DEP-GEOSRV1
  become: yes
  tasks: 

  - name: disable upgrade of java & postgresql
    dpkg_selections:
      name: openjdk-8-jre
      selection: hold
    dpkg_selections:
      name: postgresql-9.3
      selection: hold
    dpkg_selections:
      name: postgresql-server-dev-9.3
      selection: hold

  - name: Upgrade all packages to the latest version except java & postgresql
    apt:
      name: "*"
      force_apt_get: true
      state: latest
```

Not sure if this playbook is correct. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [selection: hold](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/dpkg_selections_module.html#dpkg-selections-dpkg-package-selection-selections) for the particular packages. For example

```
- dpkg_selections:
    name: openjdk-8-jre
    selection: hold
```

FWIW. See [example](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/packages.yml).

Comment: @ValidmirBotka, I updated my question, can you take a look on it? I'm struggling to find the correct place for the dpkg_selections block. Thanks!

Comment: Very probably a key to a repository is missing. You must be able to run "apt-get update" on remote before you proceed with Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

For me **dpkg_selections** didn't work.

I've created follow playbook to resolve my problem. hope works for you too

```
- name: get a list of the packages that need update
  shell: apt list --upgradable
  register: list_upgradable

- set_fact:
    upgradable_packages: "{{ list_upgradable.stdout | regex_findall('(^.+)\/', multiline=True) }}"

- apt: 
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  when: >
    item != 'linux-base' and 
    item != 'linux-firmware' and 
    item != 'linux-generic' and 
    item != 'linux-headers-generic' and
    item != 'linux-image-generic' and 
    item != 'netplan.io' and 
    item != 'ubuntu-advantage-tools' and 
    item != 'ubuntu-keyring' and 
    item != 'ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' and 
    item != 'ubuntu-server' and 
    item != 'ubuntu-standard'
  loop: "{{ upgradable_packages }}"
```